# Getting a parent script name from a child script

Tags: bash, ps, proc

CentOS/RHEL 7. GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release

I have two bash scripts, lets call them parent.sh and child.sh. The parent just calls the child thus:

```
# parent.sh
./child.sh
```

and in child.sh I want to see the actual name of the parent script. I have tried grabbing the info from /proc but I keep getting just "-bash" returned.
Here is a sample of the child.sh:

```
# child.sh
echo "My process ID is: $$"
echo "or is it $BASHPID"
echo "My Parent ID is: $PPID"
echo "Par Cmd: " `cat /proc/$PPID/cmdline`
PARENT=$(ps -o args= $PPID)
echo "Or is it: " $PARENT 


echo "Press any key to continue..........."
read x
```

When I run parent.sh I see this:

```
$ ./parent.sh 
$ ./parent.sh 
My process ID is: 14634
or is it 14634
My Parent ID is: 14633
Par Cmd:  -bash
Or is it:  -bash
Press any key to continue...........
```

What I need to get is the actual name of the script that invoked child.sh - I expect to see (at least in part) "parent.sh"

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself. All I had to do was to put the

```
#!/bin/bash
```

as the first line of the script.

(The older I get the better I was).